# Get mouse position inside an element on event: onDrop

Tags: javascript

is it possible to calculate somehow position of mouse inside an droppable container. For example mouse cursor is near right border of droppable container. I would like to know that position of mouse is to the right, or center, or left relative to the container where I wan't to drop the element

```
<div onDrop="handleDrop">... some content inside </div>
```

and js

```
const handleDrop = evt => {
 // here I am looking to calculate the mouse position inside the container
}
```

Comment: Hello @Exari, can you check https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useMouse.ts if this is working for you? :)

Comment: @halilcakar How does this library solve the problem? Additionally, the OP doesn't seem to use React...

Comment: Well these libraries are hooks for react and that useMouse calculate the current element which is also relative to it's container. I thought that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @halilcakar, yes, this is good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The event object (evt) that is passed to your handleDrop method already contains the X and Y mouse positions at the moment of drop.

```
const handleDrop = evt => {
  const mouseX = evt.clientX;
  const mouseY = evt.clientY;
}
```